# IdentityServer4 and SAML2

Tags: identityserver4

Is there an option to provide SAML2 protocol from IdentityServer4? Maybe as middlewhere?

I want to connect IdentityServer as Identity Provider to ServiceNow in order to handle the user logins centrally.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure out if there were one?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: I found this article about it, but they are using IdentityServer3. https://coding.abel.nu/2015/01/saml2-for-thinktecture-identityserver-3-with-kentor-authservices/. I have not tested it, but if you do, I'd appreciate hearing about the result.

Comment: kentor is used to create a SAML2 Service Provider. To allow IDS4 acting like a SAML2 idp,you will have to wait the september release of the SAML2 plugin for IDS4. More info here : https://www.identityserver.com/upcoming-products/